# Why $results = DB::select works while DB::table is not?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this mysql driver

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', '{database}'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', '{user}'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '{pass}'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

and in my database.php

I have 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

So When I run in the controller

```
 $results = DB::table('adventureworks2017.sales.store')->get()-first();
```

It gives me error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`store`' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `adventureworks2017`.`sales`.`store`)
```

while

```
 $results = DB::select('SELECT * FROM adventureworks2017.`sales.store` limit 5'); it workes
```

Any reason why query builder is not working wile passing statement works?

Comment: `adventureworks2017.sales.store` and `adventureworks2017.\`sales.store\`` are different…!?

Comment: I was having   $results = DB::table('adventureworks2017.`sales.store')->get()-first();

Comment: side note, no reason to use `get()` then `first()`, if you only want one record you dont need to `get` them all to then only take the `first`, just use `first()`

Comment: @lagbox I am still haveing issue this is my final statment  $results =DB::table('adventureworks2017.`sales.store`');

Comment: why do you need the database name when you are already connected to a specific db, and why `sales.store`?

Comment: Still do not know

Answer (score 1):

You can try passing a raw expression for the table name so the query builder doesn't try to decipher your dot notation into database and table, I suppose.

```
DB::table(DB::raw('sales.store'))->first();
```

Or even

```
DB::table(DB::raw('`sales.store`'))->first();
```

Comment: did you try all of them? I don't have a mysql setup in front of me to test

Comment: this one worked DB::table(DB::raw('sales.store'))->first();

Comment: DB::query()->fromRaw('sales.store')->first(): is not working